# Apple store tax form

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm located in Europe and have an app on Apple store with an individual account and I wanted to invite another developer to give him access. Apple suggested switching to a company account as this is the only way to invite another developer to the account. Now my account has switched but I'm asked to fill in a three-question tax form: Name, Country, and Type of Beneficial Owner. My problem is with "Type of Beneficial Owner" what answer should I provide? Please note that I don't intend to make any money from the app. This image [https://imgur.com/a/OzQk3FP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfiya.png) shows the possible answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you need to consult a tax professional in your country.

Comment: As I said in the post, I don't sell the app, so i'm not making any money out of it. Some developers must have experienced a similar situation. and can help